# Enabling USB debugging after re flashing the phone

Tags: android, testing, adb

I want to enable the usb debugging option in android phone automatically after my phone is flashed. 
Is there any possible way I can tell my device without usb debugging option on.
All I want is to get my USB debugging option on automatically.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Settings.System with ADB_ENABLED and android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS, but settings cannot be changed by normal application , it requires rooted phone  :(